# How to source ruby functions in bash script

Tags: ruby, bash

In bash, if I have two scripts, one with a function and the other using the first script as a source, then I can access the function in the second script. Can I do something similar with ruby?

I can do this:

test1.sh

```
doThing() {
    echo "Doing Thing"
}
```

test2.sh

```
source ./test1.sh
doThing
```

Is there a way to do something similar with ruby?
The following fails.

test1.rb

```
def doThing
    puts "Doing Thing"
end
```

test2.sh

```
source ./test1.rb
doThing
```

Thanks

Comment: It makes no sense to source ruby in bash. When you source a script, the shell executes it as bash code, so it has to be a bash script.

Comment: That makes sense, I'm new to bash programming but it's pretty awesome. Thanks for answering :)

Comment: You don't. You also don't run a COBOL program through a Java-Compiler, or use a shotgun to open a beer bottle....

Comment: @user1934428 We'll agree to disagree on the latter.

Comment: @TinyTim: Why not writing a wrapper Ruby program, which gets on the command line the name of a Ruby method, and the parameters, and then invokes the Ruby method of this name? Of course this makes only sense for String parameters, and I don't know what you plan to do with the return value of the Ruby method (since bash functions don't return a value), but perhaps it comes close to what you try to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick answer is "no", but you can call ruby programs from bash just like you can any other executables:

- Create a ruby program that takes arguments and calls the desired functions based on those arguments.
- Create a bash script that defines a bunch of functions, each of which call your ruby program with the appropriate arguments to cause it to call it's functions.
- Source that bash script of functions into your main bash script.
- Call the bash functions from that sourced script.

Comment: Awesome, I've been calling the ruby script manually, but was hoping there might be a more elegant way. But I like the idea of including the ruby script in a bash function. That will keep the same pattern I think.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to `source` Ruby, you just `ruby` Ruby, or even better, add a shell "hashbang":

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# ... Your Ruby Code
```

Then make that script executable. From there it's as simple as `./test.rb`.

You'll need to be able to forward arguments, either via `ENV`, as in `export MY_VAR=...`, or as command-line arguments, like `--my-var=...` via [`OptionParser`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.2/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html).

If you're using Ruby, it's worth keeping in mind that Ruby is a lot more capable than just shell scripting, so you may want to invert this: Let Ruby drive certain shell commands, by `system` for example, instead of the shell driving Ruby.